# Spring Boot - enable EHCache for Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I write application using Spring Boot 1.5.4 and all configurations of hibernate I have in resources/application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

### PostgreSQL ###
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myApp
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

And now I want to enable second-level memory of Hibernate to cache few tables. And I know how to do it using persistence.xml file and Ehcache file. But I don't know how to configure it in application.properties. My XML files look following:

ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="1000"
            eternal="true"
            overflowToDisk="false"/>

    <cache name="org.jpwh.model.cache.User"
           maxElementsInMemory="500"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="30"
           timeToLiveSeconds="60"/>

    <cache name="org.jpwh.model.cache.User##NaturalId"
           maxElementsInMemory="500"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="30"
           timeToLiveSeconds="60"/>

    <cache name="org.jpwh.model.cache.Item"
           maxElementsInMemory="5000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="600"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600"/>

    <cache name="org.jpwh.model.cache.Item.bids"
           maxElementsInMemory="5000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="600"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600"/>

    <cache name="org.jpwh.model.cache.Bid"
           maxElementsInMemory="100000"
           eternal="false"
           timeToIdleSeconds="600"
           timeToLiveSeconds="3600"/>
</ehcache>
```

and persistence.xml:

```
<persistence
        version="2.1"
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
                            http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="CachePU">
        <jta-data-source>myDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>org.jpwh.model</class>
        <class>org.jpwh.model.cache.Item</class>
        <class>org.jpwh.model.cache.Bid</class>
        <class>org.jpwh.model.cache.User</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache"
                      value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache"
                      value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"
                      value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/>
            <property name="net.sf.ehcache.configurationResourceName"
                      value="/cache/ehcache.xml"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries"
                      value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics"
                      value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot + JPA2 + Hibernate - enable second level cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585698/spring-boot-jpa2-hibernate-enable-second-level-cache)

Comment: Not duplicate. Here asked not only enable second-level cache but also configure it - there are some additional efforts.