# Hibernate Second Level Cache Always Call Database on fetch All entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, caching

I enabled hibernate 2nd level caching in my sprint boot 2.1.8 application by adding the following configuration:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.region.factory_class=org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
```

I also added eh cache dependancy as follows:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

I annotated an entity to be cacheable:

```
@Entity(name = "entity")
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
@Table(name = "entity")
@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "entity_id"))

    public class Entity extends ItemBase {
        private String n1;
        private String n2;
        private String n3;
        private int n4;
        @Column(name = "n_5")
        private int n5;
  //getters and setters
        }
```

Each time i call the repository class (Which extends JpaCrudRepository) and call findAll(); or findOneById(), i see hibernate log HQL queries and database is actually called.

The desired behavior is to fetch the list of entities once from database and keep them in cache, where they should be updated there using read write strategy.

Any idea how can this be acheived?

Comment: You can refer this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31585698/spring-boot-jpa2-hibernate-enable-second-level-cache

Comment: I implemented the suggested solution there, but it didnt work as well.

Comment: Don't put `@Cacheable` on the Entity. You have to annotate `@Cacheable` to method returning value.

Comment: I am trying to implement Hibernate 2nd level caching. i think you are referring to Spring cache abstraction.

Comment: Which version of hibernate are you using ?

Comment: Hey Marwan, hi. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @jumping_monkey it turns out by definition, hibernate always reaches the DB in case of select *, it then takes the pk from the query and retrieve the objects from the cache