# Spring boot jpa second level cache not being use even after configuring

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, caching, spring-data-jpa

We have set up JPA second-level cache but not working with the following configuration cache is configured properly as per logging but it not cache the database result and always fetching data from the database.

```
11:44:07.454 [main] [UserId: ] WARN net.sf.ehcache.Cache - Cache: com.Record has a maxElementsInMemory of 0.  In Ehcache 2.0 this has been changed to mean a store with no capacity limit. Set it to 1 if you want no elements cached in memory.
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true" monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
   <defaultCache eternal="false" timeToLiveSeconds="10000" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" statistics="true" maxElementsInMemory="10000" overflowToDisk="false" />
   <cache maxElementsInMemory="10000" name="Record"  eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="10000" timeToLiveSeconds="10000" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" statistics="true" />
</ehcache>
```

Enabled spring boot Caching in Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableCaching
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

      @PostConstruct
      public void init(){
        // Setting Spring Boot SetTimeZone
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
      }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Entity Record.java

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "t_record")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "c_discriminator", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Cacheable
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE,region = "Record")
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name = Record.QUERY_findAllByType, query = "SELECT r FROM Record r WHERE TYPE(r) = ?1 ORDER BY r.date DESC, r.id DESC")})
public abstract class Record implements Cloneable, XmlOutputEntity {

    /**
     * Class UID
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7146308281386143748L;
    
    public static final String QUERY_findAllByType = "findAllRecordByType";
    
}
```

Enabled second-level cache and query cache in the database configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

    protected PropConfig propConfig;

    @Autowired
    public DatabaseConfig(PropConfig propConfig) {
        this.propConfig = propConfig;
    }

    
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(propConfig.getDatabaseDriver());
        dataSource.setUrl(propConfig.getDatabaseUrl());
        dataSource.setUsername(propConfig.getDatabaseUsername());
        dataSource.setPassword(propConfig.getDatabasePassword());
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        final LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        return validator;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource,JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("com.test");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL", "true");
        props.put("logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder", "TRACE");
        props.put("show-sql", "true");
        lef.setJpaProperties(props);

        lef.getJpaPropertyMap().put("jadira.usertype.autoRegisterUserTypes", "true");
        lef.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy", "org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy");
        lef.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults", "false");
        lef.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        lef.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        lef.getJpaPropertyMap().put("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
        lef.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ALL);
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(propConfig.isShowSql());
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(propConfig.isGenerateDdl());
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(propConfig.getVendor());
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54774762/175554 can give you more ideas

Answer (score 1):

Query caching has to be enabled on a case by case basis by setting the `org.hibernate.cacheable` hint to `true`. I think with Spring Data JPA you have to annotate the repository method with `@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")`

Comment: We used query hints as well @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true") but not working. it's not cached any data always returning from db.

Comment: Then you have enable statistics and debug into `StatisticsImpl` to see when a cache miss happens and try to understand why it's not hitting the cache.

Comment: Ok let me check Statistics